# Anything wrong with my computer memory because of failures in some memory tests?

Tags: windows-7, memory, memory-card, lenovo-laptop

Recently I bought a used Lenovo Thinkpad W530 with 32G RAM in memory. This machine runs on 64bit Win 7 Pro.

I did an extended CPU test on it. No problem. However, I got FAILED in three  metrics in extended memory tests:

```
Moving inversions-32 bit
Random number sequence
Block move test
```

I can start/shutdown and use this laptop without seeing any problem. So what do the above test results mean to me in using the laptop? Should I find out which memory chip led to the failures?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Yes; You should use a process of elimination to determine which module is bad and replace it.

Comment: Do you recommend any software for determingn the bad memory chip? Any good pointers? Thanks!!!

Comment: Recommendations are basically off-limits on this site.

Comment: Xavierjazz, thanks for your input. I am new in the superuser site. Is my question within the scope of this website?

Comment: It's looks like you have faulty RAM, and need to determine which module is causing the fault. If the answer includes software recommendations then it's fine. If you're straight up asking for software, then that's off-topic.

Comment: Your asking for a software recommendation after using software that finds the error, sounds easy enough to solve, perform the tests on each module until the errors no longer happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to discover which module(s) is faulty is by testing them individually.

Take them all out, put one back in and run the tests again. It should be pretty obvious which modules are faulty after using the method.

As to why you're not noticing any problems with the RAM while using the PC? It's quite possible you simply haven't hit that part of the RAM yet in your regular day-to-day usage. You may only notice crashes when you reach very high memory usage.